# CDN for Google Cloud Functions - Configuring Endpoints with openapi-functions.yaml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, openapi, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-cdn

Following the Getting Started guide for https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions to get my Cloud Function behind a CDN. Deployed ESPv2 Beta to Cloud Run and got a provisioned CloudRun Service URL. Now I'm hitting a wall with my `openapi-functions.yaml` file. When I run the command:

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-functions.yaml \
    --project ESP_PROJECT_ID
```

I get the error response:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to service config.
'location: "openapi-functions.yaml: x-google-backend"
kind: ERROR
message: "Extension x-google-backend cannot be converted into proto type google.api.BackendRule. Details: Cannot find field: produces in message google.api.BackendRule"

 location: "openapi-functions.yaml: x-google-backend"
kind: ERROR
message: "Address field in extension x-google-backend is not a valid URL"
```

The `openapi-functions.yaml` I'm using seems to be nearly identical to the example in the tutorial and it seems like this error is saying that a Cloud Functions endpoint isn't a valid URL for CloudRun! What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help.

openapi-functions.yaml:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: "My API"
  description: "Returns something"
  version: 1.0.0
host: "SERVICENAME-IDENTIFIER-uc.a.run.app"
schemes:
  - "https"
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  "/foo":
    get:
      summary: "Returns thing"
      operationId: "foo"
      x-google-backend:
        address: "https://us-central1-my-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/bar"
        produces:
          - "application/json"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: "OK"
          schema:
            type: "string"
        '404':
          description: "Error"
          schema:
             type: "string"
        '403':
          description: "Forbidden"
          schema:
            type: "string"
```

Comment: Inside the operation, `produces` is over-indented. It should be on the same level as `responses` and not inside `x-google-backend`.

Answer (score 1):

Commented out the `produces:` statement and it works.